# PHP Web Service Queue

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, queue

I am connecting to a web service that only allows MAX (could be 1,5,10 depending on your license) concurrent connections to it from the same source. I need a solution that can in real time (not asynchronously) queue requests to the web service, ensuring that only MAX request are running at once.

I have the current set up working:

```
$jobId = $this->queue->addJob($operation);               
while ( !$this->queue->canRunJob($jobId) ) {
  //error_log("Queue full, waiting");                     
   usleep(500);                                    
}
$this->queue->runJob($jobId);
...
$this->queue->completeJob($jobId);
```

This uses a custom queue class, that uses a mysql table to track jobs, and the count the number of actively running and pending jobs.

`$this->queue->addJob` adds the new job to the database, with a status of "pending"

`$this->queue->canRunJob($jobId)` checks to see how many running jobs there are. If there are less than MAX jobs running, it will grab the next pending job from the list in FIFO order.

The PHP script is looping and sleeping until the job can run.

Once it `canRunJob` it calls `$this->queue->runJob($jobId)` which updates the job in the queue to "running" and sends the request to the webservice.

When the webservice returns the response it calls `$this->queue->completeJob($jobId)` which updates the job in the queue to  "completed".

This works 95% of the time, but if the web service provider is bogged down, or down completely, it slowly causes a process buildup on my server which locks up web and database connections.

Looking for suggestions of another way to handle this scenario without looping / sleeping

Comment: instead of a script looping and checking for queue slots, why not have your jobs simply call the "run next job" when they finish? that way there's no need for the looping script at all. Maybe have a safety script that fires up periodically, to handle the cases where a job may have barfed early and the queue emptied out because the 'run next job' bit never got called.

Comment: I like the concept, but then how does this job know to "wait" to be called? For example : Job 1 - Create a new customer (goes into queue and starts since its the only job) Job 2- Create a new customer, needs to wait for job 1 to finish. Job 1 can finish and call job 2, but job 2 needs to know its status

Comment: the job doesn't need to know anything about that. it just tells your scheduling code that the job's ending, and the scheduler takes care of figuring out what runs next. e.g. your actual jobs would be something like `<?php do_stuff(); tell_scheduler_to_run_next_job(); ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a glance at the Process component of Symfony 2. You will be able to trigger subprocesses that can do the work, e.g. the API connection. The parent can make sure that only n subprocesses are fired. Pack everything in a loop and query for each job status in there.